# Resource not found on Azure Cognitive Services

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I have created an Azure Cognitive Services resource following [the tutorial 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account?tabs=multiservice%2Clinux)

Then I have created the environment and run the following code (from [tutorial 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/web-sdk-python-quickstart)):

```
# Import required modules.
from azure.cognitiveservices.search.websearch import WebSearchAPI
from azure.cognitiveservices.search.websearch.models import SafeSearch
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

# Replace with your subscription key.
subscription_key = "YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY"

# Instantiate the client and replace with your endpoint.
client = WebSearchAPI(CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key), base_url = "YOUR_ENDPOINT")

# Make a request. Replace Yosemite if you'd like.
web_data = client.web.search(query="Yosemite")
print("\r\nSearched for Query# \" Yosemite \"")
```

However, it seems the generaed `Subscription key` and `endpoint` are not correctly read by the script since I get the following error:

> File "azu_scrapper.py", line 17, in 
>       web_data = client.web.search(query="Yosemite")   File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/linkedin-CHSAGU1d/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/search/websearch/operations/web_operations.py",
>   line 365, in search
>       raise models.ErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response) azure.cognitiveservices.search.websearch.models.error_response_py3.ErrorResponseException:
>   Operation returned an invalid status code 'Resource Not Found'

Any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `base_url` value should be :

```
https://<your endpoint>/bing/v7.0
```

I have tested on my side and it works for me :

[image]

Comment: great! that was it!!

Comment: Hi @Alvaro , glad to know your issue has been solved , pls mark this as an answer so that it will help others who has similar issues , thanks !